# Looping image slider with fixed table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

So I'm trying to build a simple portfolio site that shows off some art I've done. I'm not too concerned with writing super efficient code or anything like that. So don't scoff too much, I really don't know a lot about web dev :D

So far, on my gallery page, I've got a fixed position, single-row table working as an image slider, with each image occupying a cell in said table. I have Jquery handling all animations pretty close to exactly the way I want it (the 95% value in `animate({left: +=95%})` needs tweaking to keep everything centered, but I can handle that on my own).

What I can't figure out, however, is how to get this to loop. I've basically spent the past three days googling for an answer as well as trying out some of my own solutions, but nothing is working. I have everything I think I need in place as far as mark-up is concerned (for instance, a clone of the first image after the "last" slide, and a clone of the last image before the "first" slide). But the Jquery is befuddling me. Here is the code:

**[JSbin Demo](https://jsbin.com/homojikunu/1/edit?html,js,output)**

**CSS:**

```
td{
    padding-right: 250px;
}
.imageContainer img{
    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
#slider{
    position: fixed;
    top: 125px;
    left: -60%;
    right: 27%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 2000%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<table id="slider">
<tr>
<td class="imageContainer"><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/administrator/Desktop/drawing_photos/IMG_2062.jpg"></td>
<td class="imageContainer"><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/administrator/Desktop/drawing_photos/img_1714.jpg"></td>
<td class="imageContainer"><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/administrator/Desktop/drawing_photos/IMG_2060.jpg"></td>
<td class="imageContainer"><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/administrator/Desktop/drawing_photos/IMG_2061.jpg"></td>
<td class="imageContainer"><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/administrator/Desktop/drawing_photos/IMG_2062.jpg"></td>
<td class="imageContainer"><img src="file://Macintosh HD/Users/administrator/Desktop/drawing_photos/img_1714.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</div>
<a id="nextHitbox"></a>
<a id="prevHitbox"></a>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){

$('#nextHitbox').on('click', function(){
$('#slider').stop(true, false).animate({left: '+=-95%'}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'swing'});
});

$('#prevHitbox').on('click', function(){
$('#slider').stop(true, false).animate({left: '+=95%'}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'swing'})
});

});
```

Comment: A jsfiddle or jsBin would be helpful

Comment: Can you format your source code so it's much easier to read please? Also remove any irrelevant source code (if any)

Comment: @NewToJS Sorry about that just dumped it quickly before dinner. How does it look now? Just trimmed it down a lot. Now it just shows the CSS for the table, the HTML for the table, and the Jquery governing how the table moves upon clicking the next and previous buttons.

Comment: @sjm Yes! Here is a JSbin:    https://jsbin.com/homojikunu/1/edit?html,js,output     Note that no actual images are included bc right now they're locally stored (and uncopyrighted!) on my laptop. Clicking the two boxes on the left and right sides will cause the missing image icons to move back and forth tho, producing the same effect.

Comment: Bump? is bumping a thing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a bunch of people just came in and criticized my formatting, which I cleaned up in a matter of minutes after posting, but no one actually answered my question. This is a pretty annoying thing that I see too often on this site, but I came up with a hacky yet bug-free solution on my own over the weekend. Figured I'd share it in case anyone else out there is trying to do something similar.

Essentially, just have a fixed hitbox (like the ones already present in the code) that uses jquery to animate() by a certain amount each time you click next (or previous), so that by the time you reach the penultimate slide, it is overlapping the next button.

Then, script that hitbox to first animate() to the final slide -- which is a clone of the first slide -- and then revert the CSS for #slider to the starting position of -60%. This CSS change should be delayed using native JS function setTimeout(), which gives that animation to the final slide just enough time to complete before the CSS changes back to its original state. The code looks like this:

CSS:

```
#nextLoopbox
            {
                display: block;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 10;
                width: 115px;
                height: 82px;
                /*border: 1px solid #0000ff;*/
                left: 24570px;
                top: 315px;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<a id="nextLoopbox"></a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#nextHitbox').on('click', function()
            {
                $('#slider').stop(true, true).animate({left: '+=-95.23%'}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'swing'});
                $('#nextLoopbox').stop(true, true).animate({left: '+=-1170px'}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'swing', queue: false})    
            });

$('#nextLoopbox').on('click', function()
            {
                $('#slider').stop().animate({left: '+=-95%'}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'swing'});

                setTimeout(function() 
                    { 
                        $('#slider').css({left: '-59%'});
                        $('#nextLoopbox').css({left: '24570px'});
                    }, 1000);
            });
```

This is actually turning out to be a great, script-lite way of making an attractive, manually-controlled image slider, so hopefully it helps people who stumble upon this while furiously googling.